# Jquery next class href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want go get next class'ProductTile'

```
 getUrl = $('.ProductTile').next('.ProductTile').attr('href');
```

Unfortunetly it doesnt work - any ideas?

Website  I try to get it from:

lazienkafast.pl/baterie-kuchenne-c-3_27.html?str=50

I use proxy to laod it firstly to my localhost and then try to get href attr. Without next it works but I want it works  for second class in page not only first with the same name.

Comment: Show your html please

Comment: Try this: `$('.ProductTile').next().attr('href');`

Comment: do you want to run your code for all the links with the `ProductTile` class ? (*or just the second ?*)

Comment: You don't need anything inside the .next cuz it's follows the previous selector :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

next() work on siblings in your case the next .ProductTile is not a sibling.

```
var getUrl = $('.ProductTile').eq(1).attr('href');
```

If you want to get all this links you can use $.each

```
var getUrlArr = [];
$('.ProductTile').each(function(){
    getUrlArr.push($(this).attr('href'));
});

console.log(getUrlArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML STRUCTURA this

```
<div class='ProductTile'> // or other element
</div>
<a href='your href'> ffff </a>
```

Try this

```
getUrl = $('.ProductTile').next().attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the string inside next().

Just like this:

```
getUrl = $('.ProductTile').next().attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :)

```js
var getUrl = $(".ProductTile").next().attr("href");
```